# How do you change the syntax coloring for code snippets in Jekyll?

Tags: github, jekyll, pygments, rouge

I'm using github.io to host a website that's built with Jekyll.  I'm having a little trouble customizing my configuration.

I don't like the default syntax coloring, so I want to change the coloring scheme.  I researched this a bit, and I found some very complicated solutions that involve changing my local installation of Jekyll.  I want it to work remotely on github.io, so I don't think that would work for me even if I did it.  Is there a simple way to do this? Maybe just modifying `_config.yml`?

Comment: This is likely just a matter of editing the CSS / SCSS to your liking. I don't think there are a preset number of "themes" to choose from, but you can choose the exact colors.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I had a look at the source of a rendered page, and I see that there are span classes with names like 's', 'kn', 'n', and 'o' that seem to represent different colors in the syntax highlighting.  I could set the colors for each of these with CSS, but I was hoping that there would be themes available.

Comment: You might be able to find some themes around, but not built in to Jekyll.

Comment: I think I found the relevant SCSS file in _sass/_highlights.scss.  Editing this should be simple enough, but there are 68 different syntax classes to deal with.